# How to properly declare handlers

Tags: mysql, handler, declaration

I'm trying to add a stored procedure to MySQL scheme.
I get an error `ERROR: Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'inner_done'`.
Here's the [code](http://pastie.org/10240511)
I have to note it *doesn't* matter which handler is declared last. It's name will be in error, while the first one declared is somehow ok. I even tried playing with the plece to declare handler, e.g. create a new `BEGIN`-`END` block, but the error still gets me, randomly choosing which handfler to display as "unknown"

Comment: Do you need to _`inner_done`_ and _`done`_ before. i.e. `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;`

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't really get what code I need but I need a nested loop inside main one (so `done` handler for the main one and `inner_done` for the nested) and OFC I need this to run this `CRATE` script w/o errors

Comment: Unfortunately I can't judge what actual value should the handlers hold before and after usage, the `TRUE` is only suggested by an example I found on the Internets, **BUT** I am highly sure that the value does not matter at all and it has something to do with the variable scopes (begin-end blocks?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @RyanVincent, the error describes `inner_done` was not declare:

```
DECLARE done, inner_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
```

And wrap your inner loop in a `BEGIN - END` block.

**Edit:** the declare handler statement only defines the handler, so before this is needed the declare statement for the variable which change its value as a condition.

```
DECLARE inner_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET inner_done = TRUE;
```

Comment: You see, when these variables become basic booleans... It messes things up. I want to kinda emulate foreach loop, so `done` and `inner_done` change their state when `NOT FOUND` exception is thrown at the end of table

Comment: Now, do you *suggest* manual exception handling or is it the only solution?

Comment: It's always a good practice to set a `leave` statement and declare your nested handler inside the first loop

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity, I have finally figured it out. I just couldn't get what the f did the `DECLARE HANDLER` part do. I thought it was self-fulfilled, declaring boolean itself. Next time a bit more explanation pls, but still a big thank you